# cross field validation for composite components

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

How do I implement cross-field validation for composite components? The composite component I am using is an input text box (one for email and the second one for confirm email). I applied f:validator tag for the confirmEmail component. How to obtain the value for email composite component in the validate method. Is it UIComponent or UINamingContainer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF2.0 doesn't support cross-field validation, is there a workaround?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282466/jsf2-0-doesnt-support-cross-field-validation-is-there-a-workaround)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, your composite is a UINamingcontainer, but any component can find its children.

I suspect something like the following should work

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    UIInput first = (UIInput)component.findComponent("compositesFirstInputID");
    UIInput second = (UIInput)component.findComponent("compositessecondInputID");

    Object firstEntry = first.getSubmittedValue();
    Object secondEntry = second.getSubmittedValue();
    if(!firstEntry.equals(secondEntry))
        throw new ValidatorException(...);
}
```

Might want to add some null checking, possibly trim() and use equlasIgnoreCase.

Comment: @deepti Misread your question - Thought you had a single composite with two inputs,and the using page's composite reference had a child f:validate.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the validate method as discussed above. I think the problem with my code is where to use the f:validate tag on composite component.

```
<eg:inputText id="confirmEmail" value="backingbean.email"/>

<eg:inputText id="email" value="backingbean.email">
<f:validator validatorId="core.jsf.CompareValidator" for="inputText"/>
</eg:inputText>
```

But when I submit the form the validator is not being called. Should I wrap the validator around the component or is this the correct way of implementing.