# Why conversion is not skipped?

Tags: jsf, icefaces, jsf-1.2

I have **two input components on my page**. Each of them has a **converter** (It's a converter which checks for empty values, like JSF required one, but for some reasons I cannot use jsf one so I've made my own converter).

I also have a `ice:selectBooleanCheckbox`:

```
<ice:selectBooleanCheckbox
                    styleClass="graUserAppUserGroupAddChk"
                    value="#{userGroupTableNewRecordBean.addNewDomain}"
                    partialSubmit="true"
                    immediate="true"
                    valueChangeListener="#{userGroupTableNewRecordBean.addDomainListener}"></ice:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

As you see I put `immediate=true` attribute on it, becase when I select this checkbox I do want *the conversion phase to be skipped but it does not work*, the converters still show their warnings. Do you know why?

I also add a valueChangeListener on this checkbox and called there the renderResponse directly, based on this quote:

> ```
> So in the value changed listener method for the dropdown lists, just
> ```
>
> call  renderResponse() from the
>   FacesContext object and validation and
>   conversion is bypassed and you can
>   still do what you want.

```
public void addDomainListener(final ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
    // skip validation
    logger.info("listener calleddddddddddddd");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
}
```

Maybe a JSF guru can help?

Thanks a lot...

**UPDATE**: I know that a solution would be to put the checkbox in a separate form but I cannot afford this...

**UPDATE 2**: I've corrected some code about listener, so **now it is called when clicked but still the converter fails and render response phase is not done**...

**UPDATE 3**: This is not an icefaces issue... I've tried with a `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` and it happens the same...

Comment: Why are you using a converter instead of a validator to validate the inputs?

Comment: @BalusC - Hi Balus, I use converter because I want to check for empty values also and validators are not triggered for empty inputs...

Comment: @BaluesC - And you will ask: why you do not use jsf required attribute for this? Because, I have a strange problem in an icefaces popup with this jsf requried validation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347736/icefaces-popup-validation-issue

Comment: Do you want to validate a group of inputs together or something? If so, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282466/jsf2-0-doesnt-support-cross-field-validation-is-there-a-workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it finally...

I post here the sum up of the question and the solution.

I had a checkbox in my popup. When I **select it** I want to **show some hidden fields** but this did not work because I also had two **required fields** on the same page so jsf PROCESS_VALIDATIONS phase came up...

I thought that putting `immediate=true` will solve this, but it did not...

So, in my ValueChangeListener of the checkbox I had to **manually skip** the jsf validation phase:

```
public void addDomainListener(final ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
        // skip validation
        final PhaseId phaseId = valueChangeEvent.getPhaseId();
        final Boolean newValue = (Boolean) valueChangeEvent.getNewValue();
        if (phaseId.equals(PhaseId.ANY_PHASE)) {
            valueChangeEvent.setPhaseId(PhaseId.UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES);
            valueChangeEvent.queue();

            this.addNewDomain = newValue;
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The whole question and the functional requirement behind this all is pretty confusing. Why are you using a converter instead of a validator to validate the inputs? Why are you using a converter/validator if you don't seem to care about the conversion/validation outcome?

> *As you see I put immediate=true attribute on it, becase when I select this checkbox I do want the conversion phase to be skipped but it does not work, the converters still show their warnings.*

Putting the `immediate="true"` on input components does not skip conversion/validation. They just shifts conversion/validation to an earlier phase (i.e. it takes place in apply request values phase instead of validations phase). You basically need to remove `immediate="true"` from those inputs and put it on the command link/button in order to skip conversion/validation of those inputs. See also [Debug JSF lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html):

> ### [Okay, when should I use the immediate attribute?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html#WhenShouldIUseTheImmediateAttribute)
>
> If it isn't entirely clear yet, here's a summary, complete with real world use examples when they may be beneficial:
>
> - If set in `UIInput`(s) only, the process validations phase will be taken place in apply request values phase instead. Use this to prioritize validation for the `UIInput` component(s) in question. When validation/conversion fails for any of them, the non-immediate components won't be validated/converted.
> - If set in `UICommand` only, the apply request values phase until with update model values phases will be skipped for any of the `UIInput` component(s). Use this to skip the entire processing of the form. E.g. "Cancel" or "Back" button.
> - If set in both `UIInput` and `UICommand` components, the apply request values phase until with update model values phases will be skipped for any of the `UIInput` component(s) which does not have this attribute set. Use this to skip the processing of the entire form expect for certain fields (with immediate). E.g. "Password forgotten" button in a login form with a required but non-immediate password field.

Comment: Thanks, very clear explanation about immediate. I've learnt something new today;)