# Password validation in JSF 2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

i am just wondering what is the best way to validate password confirmation in JSF 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to validate anything you need in JSF is use [MyFaces Extval](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/EXTVAL/Index). It support cross field validation, which is a typical use case for validate passwords. See [this blog](http://jsfcorner.blogspot.com/2011/09/cross-field-validation-with-jsf-and.html) for more information about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RichFaces 4 client-side! validation based on Bean Validation (JSR303).

Bean:

```
@Size(min = 5, max = 15)
private String password1;

@Size(min = 5, max = 15)
private String password2;

@AssertTrue(message = "Passwords don't match")
public boolean checkPassword() {
    return password1.equals(password1);
}
```

Page:

```
<rich:graphValidator value="#{bean}" id="crossField">
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.password1}"/>
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.password2}"/>
    <rich:message for="crossField"/>
</rich:graphValidator>
```

Refer [here](http://richfaces.org/showcase) for more examples.

Comment: but i am using icefaces and some times pure jsf, so how can i do it without richFaces ?

Comment: IceFaces and RichFaces work well together, you can add RichFaces to your app also. I see the following options for you: 1) RichFaces 2) seam-faces 3) a workaround, refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6282466/854386.