# Cross Field Validation in JSF h:dataTable

Tags: java, jsf

I have a XHTML page in which there are four textboxes

```
<h:column >  
    <f:facet name="header">  
       <h:outputText value="Start Date" />  
    </f:facet>
    <h:inputText id="startDate" value="#{sampleVO.startDate}" />
</h:column>         
<h:column >  
    <f:facet name="header">  
       <h:outputText value="End Date" />  
    </f:facet>
    <h:inputText id="endDate" value="#{sampleVO.endDate}" />
</h:column>        
<h:column >
    <f:facet name="header">  
        <h:outputText value="Start Date" />  
    </f:facet>
    <h:inputText id="startDate1" value="#{sampleVO.startDate}" />
</h:column>         
<h:column >  
    <f:facet name="header">
       <h:outputText value="End Date" />  
    </f:facet>
    <h:inputText id="endDate1" value="#{sampleVO.endDate}" />
</h:column>
```

I need to put a validation on Start Date and End Date.  If user enters some Start and End date in id="startDate"  & id="endDate" lets say Start Date: "01/01/2012" (1jan) and End Date: 01/31/2012 and if user enters some dates on id="startDate1" and id="endDate1" id="startDate1" should always be greater thn id="endDate" i.e date Ranges should not Overlap

```
public class SampleServiceimpl implements SampleService {
    private List<SampleVO> listOfSample;

     //this function gets called when clicked on Submit button on XHTML page
     public Void submit() {
        // how can i call datesOverLaps function to check entered
        // start date and End date not overlapping, Also how to
        // display the error message on XHTML page using FacingContext
     }

     public boolean datesOverlaps(List<SampleVO> sampleVO) {
        final Date early = sampleVO.getStartDate();
        final Date late = sampleVO.getEndDate();

        for(SampleVO existing : sampleVO) {
            if(!(early.isAfter(existing.getEnd())) ||
                     (late.isBefore(existing.getStart()))){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Not sure if the above boolean function is current and would work in the scenario. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to look at cross field validation (which IMO JSF has never got right) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282466/jsf2-0-doesnt-support-cross-field-validation-is-there-a-workaround Or if you're JEE6 maybe look at Bean Validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spend 6 hours on this. But i solved it. My english is bad.

1. Add binding atribute on dataTable, pointing to UIDData field in backingbean (Bind table)

   ```
    <h:dataTable value="#{narocilo.podatki}" id="tabela" var="podatek" border="0" bgcolor="#F6FAF0" style="width:100%;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" headerClass="header" rowClasses="#{narocilo.rowClasses}"   columnClasses="align_left,align_right,align_center,align_right,align_right,align_center_konec" **binding="#{narocilo.podatkiData}"**>
   ```
2. Before the end of form ad

   ```
   <h:inputHidden id="validator" **validator="#{narocilo.validateKolicinaCena}"** value="morabiti"/>
   ```
3. validator method in backing bean

   ```
    public void validateKolicinaCena(FacesContext aContext,UIComponent aComponent,Object aValue) {

   int shrani_index = fPodatkiData.getRowIndex();

   UIComponent column_kol = fPodatkiData.getChildren().get(2);
   UIComponent column_cen = fPodatkiData.getChildren().get(5);

   for(int i=0; i<fPodatkiData.getRowCount(); i++) {

       fPodatkiData.setRowIndex(i);

       UIInput kolicina_input = (UIInput) column_kol.findComponent("kolicina");
       UIInput cena_input = (UIInput) column_cen.findComponent("cena");

       Object kolicina = kolicina_input.getLocalValue();
       Object cena = cena_input.getLocalValue();

       if(kolicina == null && cena != null) {

           kolicina_input.setValid(false);

           FacesMessage sporocilo = Sporocila.getMessage("si.alkimisticus.bitea.error", "javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED", null);
           sporocilo.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);

           aContext.addMessage(kolicina_input.getClientId(aContext), sporocilo);

       } else if(kolicina != null && cena == null) {

           cena_input.setValid(false);

           FacesMessage sporocilo = Sporocila.getMessage("si.alkimisticus.bitea.error", "javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED", null);
           sporocilo.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);

           aContext.addMessage(cena_input.getClientId(aContext), sporocilo);

       } else {
           kolicina_input.setValid(true);
           cena_input.setValid(true);
       }


   }

   fPodatkiData.setRowIndex(shrani_index);}
   ```