# How do i invoke a java script function when clicking on command button in prime faces

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

My requirement is to validate Ui component values using java script function. i would like to invoke backing bean method, once the validation is successful. How can i make it possible this requirement using primefaces 2.2 and java script. Here is the sample piece of code that i am using:

```
<p:commandButton id="saveButton" value="#{msgs['button.save.label']}"
    image="ui-icon #{msgs['button.save.icon.class']}" 
    actionListener="#{testBean.saveValues}"/>
```

Comment: why javascript? validation is built in, for cross validation, there is a workaround. [Cross validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282466/jsf2-0-doesnt-support-cross-field-validation-is-there-a-workaround)

Comment: Somehow jsf messages are not displaying in primefaces dialog window. I am not sure, if there is any bug in 2.2 version.

Comment: Doing validation by JavaScript instead of using JSF builtin validation is a terribly bad idea. You need to ask a question how to fix the real problem instead of asking how to get a hack/workaround to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop your actionListenerfrom being executed just return false in your js function of the button

this button won't execute the actionListener

```
<p:commandButton id="saveButton" value="#{msgs['button.save.label']}"
image="ui-icon #{msgs['button.save.icon.class']}" 
actionListener="#{testBean.saveValues}" onclick="return false;"/>
```

this will...

```
    <p:commandButton id="saveButton" value="#{msgs['button.save.label']}"
image="ui-icon #{msgs['button.save.icon.class']}" 
actionListener="#{testBean.saveValues}" onclick="return true;"/>
```

instead of hard coded `onclick` call your js function `onclick=myJsValidation()` it all depends on the return value of the js function

Answer (score 0):

In error case of your saveValues:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("ERROR_MESSAGE", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Error Message", "Error Message"));
```

In your xhtml, add update attribute for commandButton:

```
<p:growl id="growl_ID"/>
<p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{testBean.saveValues}" update="growl_ID"/>
```