# In what order are input fields validated?

Tags: validation, jsf

In JSFs validation phase, in what order are input fields validated?

What I thought about trying is the following: I have a group of input fields that may pass or fail conversion/validation. Also, I would like to have some input with a custom validator that produces a different outcome depending on whether all other fields passed validation or not. I can check the FacesContext for any previous messages, but I would have to make sure that this custom converter is called *after* all other fields have been checked, hence the above question. Is it simply the order in which they are defined in the Facelets-Page? If so, would this order be guaranteed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is it simply the order in which they are defined in the Facelets-Page?*

Basically, yes. The component tree will be processed recursively "the usual way". For each component first the component itself will be processed and then each of its child components in sequence.

---

> *If so, would this order be guaranteed?*

Yes. This is stated in the [JSF 2.0 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html):

> ### 2.2.3 Process Validations
>
> ...
>
> During the Process Validations phase of the request processing lifecycle, the JSF implementation must call the `processValidators()` method of the `UIViewRoot` of the tree. This will normally cause the `processValidators()` method of each component in the tree to be called **recursively**, as described in the API reference for the `UIComponent.processValidators()` method.
>
> ...

The custom converter should thus be referenced by the last component or a "stub" `<h:inputHidden>` component *after* all of the desired components. The desired components can be passed through by component bindings. See also this related answer: [JSF doesn't support cross-field validation, is there a workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282466/jsf2-0-doesnt-support-cross-field-validation-is-there-a-workaround/6282509#6282509)

As a completely different alternative, you could consider wrapping the whole thing in a composite.

Comment: personal question: do you sleep? Sometimes, after yet another faster-than-2-min response one starts to wonder... ;)

Comment: Regarding your edit: What would happen if I wrap it in a composite component? Does the component itself have an invalid status that depends on its contents? (PS: got notified of some comment of yours but can't see it here. Did you delete it?)