# JSF validation in action phase

Tags: validation, jsf

We have a JSF based web application which submits the input form data to a *web service* and then displays the response provided  by *web service*.

It is the *web service* that validates the input data entered by the user. I'm not sure how we can use the `JSF validation` here. As per my understanding JSF validates individual components in the view. But it will be very expensive operation to make a web service request each time.

Instead, when the user submits the form, we skip all validations, make the web service request in the action method. Based on the response from the web service, can we programmatically tell that the particular UI component is invalid?

Could you please provide your suggestion on this?

**Environment:-**

```
JSF 2.0
WebSphere Application Server 8.5
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> *Based on the response from the web service, can we programmatically tell that the particular UI component is invalid?*

Yes, you can do that by calling [`UIInput#setValid()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#setValid%28boolean%29), passing `false`. Here's the complete piece:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
UIInput input = (UIInput) context.getViewRoot().findComponent("form:input");
input.setValid(false);
context.addMessage(input.getClientId(context), message);
context.validationFailed();
```

The `FacesContext#validationFailed()` doesn't need to be called on a per-input basis by the way.

Comment: Just one quick comment. I didn't find context.setValidationFailed(Boolean), instead context.setValidationFailed() was there.

Comment: @BalusC Why do we need to call `context.validationFailed();`?

Comment: @Geek: For exact the reason mentioned in http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#validationFailed() Note that this is implicitly already done when a `ValidatorException` with the message is thrown but not when you set the message manually which doesn't notify JSF in any way about the validation failure.

Comment: @BalusC We are using JSF 1.2. Compiler can not find `FacesContext#validationFailed()`. What is the JSF1.2 way of achieving the same?

Comment: @BalusC you said in your comment "... with the message is thrown but not when you set the message manually which doesn't notify JSF in any way about the validation failure. ", I also saw the http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#validationFailed() but is not `input.setValid(false);` sufficient ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this tutorial](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/jsf/jsf2/JSF2-Validation.pdf) - section "Manual validation".

This is probably what you're trying to accomplish.

**Manual validation**

- Use string properties for bean (Use try/catch blocks to handle illegal data)
- Do validation in setter methods and/or action controller
- Return null to redisplay form
- Create custom error messages and store in FacesMessage
- Use h:messages to display list of error messages (If there are no messages, this doesn’t output anything)

For example in bean:

```
public void setBidAmount(String bidAmount) {
    this.bidAmount = bidAmount;
    try {
        numericBidAmount = Double.parseDouble(bidAmount);
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {}
}
```

And in action method:

```
public String doBid() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (getNumericBidAmount() <= 0.10) {
        context.addMessage(null, 
        new FacesMessage("Bid amount must be at least $0.10."));
    }
    ...
    if (context.getMessageList().size() > 0) {
        return(null);
    } else {
        doBusinessLogicForValidData();
        return("show-bid1");
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what the OP is concretely asking.