# How to get rid of highlighting for invalid components in JSF/Primefaces

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces, converters

I'm using Primefaces 3.5.2, Mojara 2.1.2. I have a main xhtml page and a dialog in this page. Below is a simple example

```
<h:form>
   <p:commandButton id="btn1" oncomplete="dlg.show()" update="dlg" process="@form"/>
</h:form>

   <p:dialog id="dlg" widgetVar="dlg">
      <h:form>
         <p:tabView id="tabview" activeIndex="..always 0 ...">
           <p:tab id="tab1">
             <p:panelGrid>
               <p:inputText id="input1" value="#{myBean.integer}"/>

             p:selectOneMenue is rendered wrong, if the dialog is reopened.
               <p:selectOneMenu id="select" value="#{myBean.listVal}" filter="true" style="width:100%">
                 <p:selectItems value="#{myBean.list}" />
               </p:selectOneMenu>
               <p:commandButton action="#{myBean.ok}" value="ok" oncomplete="..." update="dlg" process="@form"/>
               <p:commandButton action="#{myBean.cancel}" value="cancel"  update="dlg" process="@form"oncomplete="dlg.hide()"/>
             <p:panelGrid>
           </p:tab>
           <p:tab id="tab2">
            ...
           </p:tab>
         </p:tabView>
      </h:form>
   </p:dialog>
```

Managed Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
class MyBean {
   Integer integer;
   String listVal;

   public Integer getInteger() { ... }
   public void setInteger (Integer i) { ... }
   public void ok() { ... }
   public void cancel() { ... }

   public List<SelectItem> getList() { ... }
   public getListVal () { ... } 
   public setListVal (..) { ... }

}
```

If I open the dialog, write in input field (input1) something wrong, e.g. text instead of number, and click "ok", then the input will be invalid and marked as red. I close the dialog with cancel or close button. If I reopen the dialog  the input field remains marked as red. I don't want this behaviour.

Another problem: in invalidated state "select"-Component from Primefaces changes often the size. If I replace p:selectOneMenu with h:selectOneMenu then the component has the right size.

My **question** is how you can change the state of JSF/Primefaces so that the JSF will be in "validate" state after you reopen the dialog and JSF will not show highlighting.

I have tried to change the component state with setValid(true)  for all components in "myBean.cancel" it does not help however. Similar as in this question
[How to mark other components invalid in a custom multi-field validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376875/jsf2-primefaces-how-to-highlight-the-inputtext-border-with-red-color)

### Update

Thank you, the problem with red borders is disappeared. But I have another one very similar problem. see: [p:SelectOneMenue changes size in Primefaces/JSF if Converter/Validator error occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030920/pselectonemenue-changes-size-in-primefaces-jsf-if-converter-validator-error-occ)

Comment: Did you try: <p:commandButton id="btn1" update="dlg" oncomplete="dlg.show()" /> ?

Comment: @RongNK Yes did, I've ommited all the details in the example to simplicity. But now I will write more details.

Comment: You try: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/resetInput.jsf

Comment: As @RongNK suggests, put reset input inside the cancel commandbutton tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For resetting input fields consider using Omnifaces. Omnifaces provides a ResetInputAjaxActionListener for this. See here for more: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/eventlisteners/ResetInputAjaxActionListener.

**Update 1**

Since PrimeFaces 3.4 you can also use `<p:resetInput>` instead of Omnifaces `ResetInputAjaxActionListener`. See here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/resetInput.jsf

**Update 2**

And since JSF 2.2 you can also use `<f:ajax ... resetValues="true"/>` or `<f:resetValues render="...">`.