# PrimeFaces input components are not highlighted on validation error

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, highlight

I am using Seam 2.3.1 Final. And I have added the Custom EmailValidation on my form.

```
@Name("emailValidator")
@BypassInterceptors
@org.jboss.seam.annotations.faces.Validator
public class EmailValidator implements Validator {
    private static final String EMAIL_REGEX = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    /**
     * <a href="http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-email
     * -address-with-regular-expression/">Source</a> <br/>
     * Modification : autorisation des "-" dans le nom de domaine <br/>
     * Exemple valide : jean-michel-75440.exemple42@email-pro.mon-entreprise.com
     */
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
                         Object value) throws ValidatorException {

        /* Create the correct mask */
        Pattern mask = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_REGEX);

        /* Get the string value of the current field */
        String emailField = (String) value;

        /* Check to see if the value is a valid email */
        Matcher matcher = mask.matcher(emailField);

        if (!matcher.matches()) {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();
            message.setDetail("E-posta adresi geçerli değil!");
            message.setSummary("E-posta Hatasi");
            message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);

            throw new ValidatorException(message);
        }
    }

    public String getValidatorId() {
        return "emailValidator";
    }
}
```

And the JSF

```
 <h:form id="editPersonelForm">

    <p:messages showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true"/>

        <p:outputLabel for="personName" value="Ad"/>
        <p:inputText id="personName" placeholder="Ad" value="#{personelBean.personel.name}" required="true"
                     requiredMessage="Ad alanını doldurmak zorunludur." validatorMessage="Ad alanı zorunludur.">


        <p:outputLabel for="personEmail" value="E-Posta"/>
        <p:inputText id="personEmail" value="#{personelBean.personel.email}" placeholder="E-Posta" >
            <f:validator validatorId="emailValidator" />
        </p:inputText>

        <p:outputLabel for="personelSaveBtn" value=""/>
        <p:commandButton id="personelSaveBtn" value="Kaydet"
                         action="#{personelBean.saveOrPersist}"
                         oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) PF('personEdit').hide();"
                         update=":tableForm" ajax="true">

        </p:commandButton>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

It works, when I type invalid email, it gives error message text. However, input fields does not switch error-state mode. There is no redline border of input anymore.

Comment: Also not when you explicitly include the inputs in `update`? Which PrimeFaces version?

Comment: Thank you! `update=":tableForm :editPersonelForm"` solve my problem!

Comment: I wonder, editPersonelForm being inside a dialog cause the rerender problem? Or Custom Validation make a rerender trouble. However, your advice works... if you want write as answer, I will check, or i will write the answer..

Comment: I already posted it half a hour ago. Perhaps you forgot to F5?

Comment: you are right... by the way, this is a example of the email validation in Seam 2.3 and PrimeFaces 5.3... I have not found a complete example before. It can be helpful for others looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly cover the inputs in ajax-update as well. One way is adding `@form` which represents the current form.

```
<p:commandButton ... update=":tableForm @form" />
```

Or by its explicit ID.

```
<p:commandButton ... update=":tableForm :editPersonelForm" />
```

Another way is using a [PFS/jQuery selector](http://%20%20%20%20%3Cp:commandButton%20...%20update=%22:tableForm%20@form%22%20/%3E) to reference only the inputs.

```
<p:commandButton ... update=":tableForm @(#editPersonelForm :input)" />
```

A completely different way is using OmniFaces [`<o:highlight>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/highlight) to put PrimeFaces own style sheet on the associated inputs (and labels) so that you never need to worry about explicitly ajax-updating them.

```
<o:highlight styleClass="ui-state-error" />
```