# Null Pointer Exception in custom validation in JSF 2

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces

I am having 3 h:inputText : Name, Start Number and End Number.

I have two custom validation functions validateName and validateNumber as shown in the Bean class.
The functions are called as shown in show.xhtml.

Out of which validateName() runs successfully but at validateNumber() generates the error as follows:

show.xhtml @83,93 validator="#{myBean.validateNumber}": java.lang.NullPointerException

The line 83 is:

```
<h:inputText id="idstart" value="#{myBean.start}" validator="#{myBean.validateNumber}"/>
```

show.xhtml:

```
<h:inputText id="name" required="true" requiredMessage="Name cannot be empty!" value="#{myBean.name}" validator="#{myBean.validateName}">
<rich:message for="name"/>

<h:inputText id="idstart" value="#{myBean.start}" validator="#{myBean.validateNumber}"/>
<rich:message for="id1"/>

<h:inputText id="id2" value="#{myBean.end}" />
```

SessionScoped bean:

```
import javax.faces.application.Application;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;
public class MyBean
{
private Integer start;
private Integer end;
private String name;

public void validateName(FacesContext context,UIComponent component,Object value)throws ValidatorException
    {
        String name=value.toString();
        /*Code for having Unique name */
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Unique Validation failed","Name used is already existing");
                 msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                 throw new ValidatorException(msg);
            }           
        }
    }

public void validateNumber(FacesContext context,UIComponent component,Object value)throws ValidatorException
    {

        if(start > end)
            {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Number Validation failed","Start Number Should be less the End Number");
                 msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                 throw new ValidatorException(msg);
            }           
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, probably `start` and/or `end` are `null`. Debug this. Where are you initializing those two variables I don't see this?

Comment: Do you have the setStart and setEnd methods in your bean?

Comment: A non-systemic NPE like this is almost certainly caused by something you overlooked. Are you sure your bean is declared `@SessionScoped`? and `value` is not null? Post the full stack trace here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be accessing the bean's properties directly from inside a validator. They are namely not been set yet at that point. JSF needs to process the validations (phase 3) first before updating the model values (phase 4). You should instead be grabbing the value from the validator method's 3rd argument or from the component tree.

In your `validateNumber` method, the 3rd argument is the start date. The end date is at that point not converted/validated yet. You'd need to manually grab it form *either* the request parameter map,

```
String end = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("formIc:id2");
```

*(where `formId` is the `id` of your parent `<h:form>`; the `id2` is by the way a terrible choice, rather choose something more sensible and self-documenting, such as `end`)*

*or* as submitted value from the component tree:

```
UIForm formComponent = (UIForm) component.getNamingContainer();
UIInput endComponent = (UIInput) formComponent.findComponent("id2");
String end = endComponent.getSubmittedValue();
```

#### See also:

- [JSF doesn't support cross-field validation, is there a workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282466/jsf2-0-doesnt-support-cross-field-validation-is-there-a-workaround/6282509#6282509)
- [OmniFaces - `<o:validateOrder>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateOrder)