# JSF page validation in Java and generated component IDs issue

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, myfaces

I have a question according to `<h:message for="" />` JSF object. I have a JSF 1.1 (yes, unfortunatelly) myFaces project. I've prepared a simple JSP file with label, inputText and message holder:

```
<h:form id="sacLinkForm">
    <cblFaces:outputLabel for="dedicatedCashAccountNumber"
        value="#{appBundle.KUSTA_DEDICATED_CASH_ACCOUNT_NUMBER}"/>
    <t:inputText id="dedicatedCashAccountNumber"
        value="#{createController.modelFE.sacLink.dedicatedCashAccountNumber}"/>
    <h:message id="dedicatedCashAccountNumberError"
        for="dedicatedCashAccountNumber" />
</h:form>
```

Also I've created simple validation method:

```
public static boolean validate(SACLink link) {
    boolean isError = false;
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();
    message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);

    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(link.dedicatedCashAccountNumber)) {
        //MessageUtils.addErrorMessage("dedicatedCashAccountNumber", "Dedicated Cash Account Number is mandatory");
        message.setSummary("Field mandatory");
        message.setDetail("Dedicated Cash Account Number is mandatory");
        context.addMessage("sacLinkForm:dedicatedCashAccountNumber", message);
        isError = true;
    }
    return !isError;
}
```

My problem is with `sacLinkForm:dedicatedCashAccountNumber` because compiled JSP has generated id (f.e. `_idJsp12:DynTab2:DynView2:tabK.....er:vKustaMa....Controller:sacLinkForm:dedicatedCashAccountNumber`) and it probably causes that `addMessage` method doesn't correspond with `h:message for=".."` attribute.

So the message is not displayed correctly because java could not find correct `h:message` object. Is there any way how to set message to the correct `h:message` from Java? I assume that there is no way how to force 'constant' component ID in the JSF 1.1 pages.

Thank you.

Comment: did you try to add prependId="false" to the form ? and use dedicatedCashAccountNumber instead of sacLinkForm:dedicatedCashAccountNumber

Comment: @Laabidi: `prependId` was introduced in JSF 1.2. OP is using JSF 1.1.

Comment: Ah sorry, I confirm that. I was just checking that (after a doubt).
Even prependId was not available in JSF 1.1

Comment: as @BalusC wrote. prependId and other Id modificators were added in next JSF releases. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be manually performing validation in a JSF action method at all. You should utilize JSF builtin validation facilities. You should use a normal JSF [`Validator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/validator/Validator.html). Any `ValidatorException` which you throw from that will end up in the right message component.

Replace that `validate()` method by the following class:

```
public class AccountNumberValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();
            message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            message.setSummary("Field mandatory");
            message.setDetail("Dedicated Cash Account Number is mandatory");
            throw new ValidatorException(message);
        }
    }

}
```

Register it in `faces-config.xml` as follows:

```xml
<validator>
     <validator-id>accountNumberValidator</validator-id>
     <validator-class>com.example.AccountNumberValidator</validator-class>
</validator>
```

Use it in the view as follows:

```html
<t:inputText id="dedicatedCashAccountNumber"
    value="#{createController.modelFE.sacLink.dedicatedCashAccountNumber}"
    validator="accountNumberValidator" />
```

That's it. Note that the JSF action method won't be invoked if validation (or conversion) has failed. No need for nonsensicial `isError` clutter as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was also considering usage of dedicated validator for each rule. But I don't want to create new validator for every new validation rule. But you are right, this is definitely working and clean solution. But I am little bit afraid of some more complex validation rules like f.e. dependent form fields (like startDate > endDate; checkbox == checked then another field will be validated differently). But I can most of the cases validate them after in the controller with returning error message to error summary tab (not to field h:message) and block further progress.

Comment: Multi-field validation is explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282466/jsf2-0-doesnt-support-cross-field-validation-is-there-a-workaround/6282509#6282509 If you happen to use JSF2 or understand JSF2 source code, OmniFaces has several open source solutions, see "validators" section on the bottom of the left menu: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/