# Difference between <h:inputXxx validator> attribute and <f:validator> tag

Tags: validation, jsf

What is the difference between using `<h:inputXxx validator>` attribute and `<f:validator>` tag?

```
<h:inputText ... validator="someValidator">
```

```
<h:inputText ...>
    <f:validator validatorId="someValidator" />
```

When should I use which one?

Comment: The only apparent difference is that `validatorId` for `<f:validator/>` must refer to a named instance of `Validator` as a standalone class. With `validator` you can refer to an instance of validator Or a method that implements the [validator method signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/validator/Validator.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `validator` attribute allows you to reference a standalone managed bean method instead of just the validator ID like so:

```
<h:inputSomething validator="#{bean.validate}" />
```

with a `validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)` method in the backing bean class without the need for a `Validator` implementation.

The `<f:validator>` allows you to register multiple validators on the input instead of only one via `validator` attribute.

Which one to use depends on the concrete functional requirement. Just choose the one that requires the least amount of code so that you end up in clean code.

Comment: When does the validation actually happen? When the value changes? If so  `value="true"` will never fire validation , right ?

Comment: It will obviously always happen. If you intend to listen on a value change only, use a value change listener instead of a validator.

Comment: I took this example from a [previous answer of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6282509/1168904). I am not getting the importnace of `value=true` part.

Comment: This is a completely unrelated question which you didn't cover in your initial question. It wasn't obvious from your initial question that you took the example from there. In that example, it's been used to trigger validation, because empty fields by default only trigger `required="true"` validation.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume we have Spring Configs here.

Then in first case "fooValidator" will be one `<beanId>` and that respective class(i.e validator class) will be called and validation will happen.

In second case, that should be something like `"#{someBean.validationMethod}"`. In this case that validation method will be called.

First one is good approach. Because in that case our validator class extends JSF's default Validator interface and implement validate() method.

Second is good, if you want to customize the validation process.

First will be called at the time of rendering of your page and not sure about second very much. But I think, that is also called at the time of rendering.