# Omnifaces ValidateOrder throws null pointer exception when end date is null

Tags: jsf-2, omnifaces

I am using omnifaces validate order component in JSF application to validate start date and end date similar to one show cased. But, when end date is null in my application this throws null pointer exception below. How to handle this.

```
<app:calendar label="#{msg['gang.effectiveDate']}" property="effectiveDate" required="true"/>
<app:calendar label="#{msg['gang.expiryDate']}" property="expiryDate"/>

<o:validateOrder id="order" type="lte" components="effectiveDate expiryDate" 
                                             message="#{msg['startdate.lte.enddate']}" showMessageFor="effectiveDate" />
```

Exception thrown

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:290)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:157)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:146)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:472)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:155)
    at org.omnifaces.component.validator.ValidateOrder$Type$2.invoke(ValidateOrder.java:75)
    at org.omnifaces.component.validator.ValidateOrder$Type$2.invoke(ValidateOrder.java:71)
    at org.omnifaces.component.validator.ValidateOrder$Type.validateOrder(ValidateOrder.java:105)
    at org.omnifaces.component.validator.ValidateOrder.validateValues(ValidateOrder.java:141)
    at org.omnifaces.component.validator.ValidateMultipleFields.validateComponents(ValidateMultipleFields.java:187)
    at org.omnifaces.component.validator.ValidatorFamily.processValidators(ValidatorFamily.java:63)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.Panel.processValidators(Panel.java:287)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.Dialog.processValidators(Dialog.java:385)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at
```

Comment: FYI: this is fixed in upcoming OmniFaces 2.0 / 1.1.0/

Comment: Tested on Omnifaces 2.0, this worked. Thanks BalusC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either check for `expiryDate` value before submit to prevent nullPointerException or add this code to your `<o:validateOrder>` to disable it when `expiryDate` is null :

```
<o:validateOrder ... disabled="#{empty param['yourForm:yourNullableField']}" />
```

See : [OmniFaces validateOrder disabling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908074/omnifaces-validateorder-disabling)