# p:dataTable form submission throws java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, validation

i followed this approach [JSF doesn't support cross-field validation, is there a workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282466/jsf2-0-doesnt-support-cross-field-validation-is-there-a-workaround) to have a multicomponent validator. In my case six input fields inside each row in a datatable(primefaces). Validation process seems to work right but strange thing is, when i only have one row, the form is submitted, validated, backing bean populated and so on. When i have more than one row,, the form is submitted, validated, but save method on backing is not called.
Debug in browser prints in http response:

```
class java.lang.NumberFormatException>>
```

And using a phase listener to log component life cycle i see this:

```
2014-09-30/23:23:25.579/BST DEBUG LifeCycleListener:24:[http-apr-8080-exec-4] - START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
2014-09-30/23:23:25.581/BST DEBUG LifeCycleListener:24:[http-apr-8080-exec-4] - START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
2014-09-30/23:23:25.697/BST DEBUG LifeCycleListener:19:[http-apr-8080-exec-4] - END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
2014-09-30/23:23:25.701/BST DEBUG LifeCycleListener:19:[http-apr-8080-exec-4] - END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
2014-09-30/23:23:25.702/BST DEBUG LifeCycleListener:24:[http-apr-8080-exec-4] - START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
2014-09-30/23:23:25.702/BST DEBUG LifeCycleListener:24:[http-apr-8080-exec-4] - START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
2014-09-30/23:23:26.270/BST DEBUG LifeCycleListener:19:[http-apr-8080-exec-4] - END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
2014-09-30/23:23:26.270/BST DEBUG LifeCycleListener:19:[http-apr-8080-exec-4] - END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
```

I'm not using any converter, just my custom validator. What am i doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for helping!
Here is the .xhtml - http://pastebin.com/9YqYGj3g
The backing bean - http://pastebin.com/TsvqHSjn
and the validator - http://pastebin.com/0H1CrqMR
Backing bean is in Session scope and project has on web.xml

`code`<context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
How can i provide here the stack trace? Do i need a global exception handler and log the stack track there?

Comment: @BalusC please ignore this question, exception thrown is inside validator. I'll simplify this code piece. Thanks anyway!