# Cross-field validation with Omnifaces: "Enter X and Y or enter Z"

Tags: validation, jsf, omnifaces

When using OmniFaces, is there the possibility to validate if fields X and Y are filled out or Z?

For example *"Enter firstname and lastname or enter your birthday"* (firstname and lastname are two seperate fields).

What I already have:

```
<o:validateOneOrMore id="l3" components="firstname lastname birthday" />
```

Context: [JSF doesn't support cross-field validation, is there a workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282466/jsf-doesnt-support-cross-field-validation-is-there-a-workaround)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the requirement by adding a `<o:validateAllOrNone>` referring the both name fields *before* the `<o:validateOneOrMore>`.

So, basically:

```
<o:validateAllOrNone components="firstname lastname" />
<o:validateOneOrMore components="firstname lastname birthday" />
```