# Can we pass parameters to the JSF Validator

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2

Can we pass parameter values to JSF Validator in xhtml page. 
For example `<h:inputText value='#{myvalue}' validator='#{validator.method(param)}' />` or is there any way to do so.
 Because i have a dataTable in which there are two columns with fields dealerType (`selectOneMenu`) and dealerNumber(`inputText`) where dealerNumber text strength validation is based on previous dealerType.

Comment: Yes using `<f:attribute name="..." value="#{...}"/>` and binding to another component of your interest, if necessary. Basically, you are looking for the cross field validation criteria ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6282509/1391249)).

Answer (score 0):

You may access the value of the selectOneMenu in the validator method of the inputText like this:

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) 
        throws ValidatorException {
    UIInput input = (UIInput) context.getViewRoot().findComponent("selectOneMenuID");
    String str = (String) input.getSubmittedValue();
    // now do the validation based on 'str'
}
```

Comment: Cant get unique `selectOneMenuID` as it is in a dataTable and JSF adds rowIndex in the `selectOneMenuID`