# Validating sum of multiple input texts in JSF 2

Tags: jsf-2.2

I have three input texts in my xhtml and I want to check if the sum of those three fields equals to 100. What is the best way of validating multiple fields in my situation? Is it possible to use a validator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSF doesn't support cross-field validation, is there a workaround?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282466/jsf-doesnt-support-cross-field-validation-is-there-a-workaround)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
<h:inputHidden id="inputhiddenId" value="true" validator="#{managedBean.checkSum}"/>
<h:message for="inputhiddenId" style="color: red"/>
...
```

and

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ManagedBean implements Serializable {
...

    public void checkSum(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        double val = filed1 + field2 + field3;
        if (val != 100.0) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error",
                "Sum of fields must be equal to 100");
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

solved my problem.

But also `<h:inputText ...` components for field1, field2 and field3 must embrace `<f:ajax .../>`.