How to pass and than get attribute to validator?
How to get in the PasswordValidatorImpl the value of entire object "userView.selectedUser" that user currently fulfilling from GUI ?
<p:password id="pwd1" 
    value="#{userView.selectedUser.password}"
    validator="#{passwordValidator.validate}"
    match="pwd2" 
    feedback="true"
    required="true" 
    requiredMessage="Please enter value">
        <f:attribute name="selectedUser" value="#{userView.selectedUser}" />
</p:password>

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import jakarta.faces.view.ViewScoped;

@Component("userView")
@ViewScoped
public class UserView implements Serializable {

    @Getter @Setter private User selectedUser;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        selectedUser = new User();    
    }
}

public class PasswordValidatorImpl implements PasswordValidator, Validator<Object>, Serializable 
{
    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException 
    {
        User user = (User) component.getAttributes().get("selectedUser");
        /*
        At this point, value for userView.selectedUser.password is set correctly and I can get it with Object value, but I need entire object selectedUser, not password specifically.

        How do I get in here selectedUSer object?
        */
    }
}

appreciate the help,
--vs

It's only set when the validation has succeeded. The currently processed value is represented by the 3rd method argument Object value.

@BalusC, sorry, incorrect question, I've edited original question: looking for the way to get currently modified in GUI entire userView.selectedUser object and not just userView.selectedUser.password (which of course is given by Object value). Thank you.

It's the correct approach. You might want to describe in detail how exactly it isn't working out for you. E.g. it is null? Or it returns a completely different instance than expected? If so which one exactly? Etc.

The value for userView.selectedUser does not have currently added values for other details like say username, lastname, dob, etc that user just added in the GUI. Looks like validator is looking into userView.selectedUser.password only. I think instead of using validator I'll use Save method that sumbit entire view and inside save() than I'll get the userView.selectedUser.

Model values are only updated during update model values phase, not during validations phase. Add <p:ajax/> to every other input field of interest to let it immediately update the model value on change. The correct term to research futher on this in your JSF book is "JSF lifecycle". See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/6282466 which is also referenced halfway in the answer of the abovelinked duplicate.
